# use the TYPE from the tempate type argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-functions

I would like to use the type information from a class template argument list.

Working example with quick *workaround*:

```
struct NoParam {};
template< typename A = NoParam,
          typename B = NoParam,
          typename C = NoParam,
          typename D = NoParam,
          typename E = NoParam,
          typename F = NoParam >
struct TypeList
{
  typedef A T1;
  typedef B T2;
  typedef C T3;
  typedef D T4;
  typedef E T5;
  typedef F T6;
};

template<typename... Types>
class Application
{
   Application()
   {
      // the actual code will store the created instances in a tuple or map..
      std::make_unique< TypeList<Types...>::T1 > ();
      std::make_unique< TypeList<Types...>::T2 > ();
      std::make_unique< TypeList<Types...>::T3 > ();
      std::make_unique< TypeList<Types...>::T4 > ();
      std::make_unique< TypeList<Types...>::T5 > ();
      std::make_unique< TypeList<Types...>::T6 > ();
   }
}
```

Is there any generic way...

- to iterate over Types and get the type info (for creating instances)
- no hard coded for only limited 6 types in the example

Comment: Use variadic templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not re-invent the wheel, you can use `std::tuple` and `std::tuple_element_t` for that:

```
template<typename... T>
using TypeList = std::tuple<T...>;

template<int I, typename T>
using Type = std::tuple_element_t<I, T>;

template<typename... Types>
class Application {
    Application() {
        std::make_unique<Type<0, TypeList<Types...>>> ();
        std::make_unique<Type<1, TypeList<Types...>>> ();
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

---

Iterate over the types is quite simple now.
It follow a minimal, working example to show you how you can do that:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename... T>
using TypeList = std::tuple<T...>;

template<int I, typename T>
using Type = std::tuple_element_t<I, T>;

template<typename... Types>
class Application {
    using MyTypeList = TypeList<Types...>;

    template<std::size_t... I>
    void iterate(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        // demonstration purposes, here I'm simply creating an object of the i-th type
        int _[] = { 0, (Type<I, MyTypeList>{}, 0)... };
        (void)_;
    }

public:
    void iterate() {
        iterate(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types)>{});
    }

    Application() {
        std::make_unique<Type<0, MyTypeList>> ();
        std::make_unique<Type<1, MyTypeList>> ();
        // and so on...  
    }
};

int main() {  
    Application<int, float> app;
    app.iterate();
}
```

Note that `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` are available since C++14. Anyway, you can find online several implementations to be used if you are constrained to C++11.
Otherwise, you can also iterate over the types with a couple of recursive _sfinae'd_functions that check if `sizeof...(Types)` has been reached.

Comment: how could I do in iterate() if I want to use each type to create container?  std::vector<Type<I, MyTypeList>> ??

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with those containers. If you can give me more details, I'll add an example to the answer...

Comment: I see. I know how to use them now. But the trick of braced-init-list { 0, ( (void) XXXX, 0) ... } is new to me. What keyword can I do further research in google?

Comment: It's a pack expansion. I guess you can find more details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the struct `typeList` indexing the variadic type using something like

```
struct noTypeInList
 { };

template <std::size_t, typename ...>
struct typeSel;

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct typeSel<0U, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = T0; };

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct typeSel<N, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = typename typeSel<N-1U, Ts...>::type; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeSel<N>
 { using type = noTypeInList; };
```

So

```
std::make_unique< TypeList<Types...>::T1 > ();
```

become

```
std::make_unique< typeSel<0, Types...>::type > ();
```

The following is a full C++11 example, in case you want a `std::tuple` of `std:unique_ptr`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

struct noTypeInList
 { };

template <std::size_t, typename ...>
struct typeSel;

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct typeSel<0U, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = T0; };

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct typeSel<N, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = typename typeSel<N-1U, Ts...>::type; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeSel<N>
 { using type = noTypeInList; };

template <std::size_t ...>
struct range
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct rangeH 
 { using type = typename rangeH<N-1U, N-1U, Next ... >::type; };

template <std::size_t ... Next >
struct rangeH<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = range<Next ... >; };

template<typename... Types>
class Application
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Types>...> tpl;

      template <std::size_t ... rng>
      Application (const range<rng...> &)
         : tpl{std::make_tuple(std::unique_ptr<
                  typename typeSel<rng, Types...>::type>()...)}
          { }

   public:
      Application () : Application(typename rangeH<sizeof...(Types)>::type())
       { }
 };

int main()
 {
   Application<int, float, int, std::tuple<double, long>>  a;
 }
```

This is only an example to use of `typeSel` because `Application` can be simply written as

```
template<typename... Types>
class Application
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Types>...> tpl;

   public:
      Application () : tpl{std::make_tuple(std::unique_ptr<Types>()...)}
       { }
 };
```

If you can use a C++14 compiler, you can use `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` (and delete `range` and `rangeH`) and `Application` can become

```
template<typename... Types>
class Application
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Types>...> tpl;

      template <std::size_t ... rng>
      Application (const std::index_sequence<rng...> &)
         : tpl{std::make_tuple(std::unique_ptr<
                  typename typeSel<rng, Types...>::type>()...)}
          { }

   public:
      Application () : Application(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types)>())
       { }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way, use a **recursive template class**:

```
template<class...> class Application;

template<class T> class Application<T>{
  public:
   Application()
   {
      std::make_unique<T> ();
   }
};
template<class T,class...Others> class Application<T,Others...>
                        :  public Application<Others...>{
  public:
   Application():Application<Others...>()
   {
      std::make_unique<T> ();
   }
};
```